# unix move command regex

Tags: regex, unix, filenames, mv

I have a bunch of files in the format

`blahblah1.java.bak`, `blahblah2.java.bak`, etc.

And I want to change all the files ending with `.bak` to just `.java`. Is it possible to do this using the `mv` command? Perhaps something like `mv (.*\.java)\.bak $1`?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
for i in *java.bak ; do mv "$i" `basename "$i" .bak` ; done
```

or

```
for i in *java.bak ; do mv "$i" "${i%.bak}" ; done
```

if you are in bash. Command line file matching is not exactly the same as a regex in, say, Perl or `=~` comparison in bash and you cannot capture a group. Note the differences: for example, `*` and `.` have a very different meaning.

Comment: Nothing, just didn't know you can do that :D

Comment: I was momentarily confused; that happens with old age. It seems to me that every day new features are added to bash ("*in my times we had no fancy ${i%.pdf}, we used basename and we were happy to have it*") and I thought that bash might have gained something like real regexes :-)