# Renaming part for file using mv command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

i want to rename a file using mv command in shell script
now file is in the format `foo-<date>.tar.gz` i want to rename it to `foo1-<date>.tar.gz.`
i tried, cut the foo and rename it and concatenate and all but i want to something very simple follows
`mv foo*.tar.gz foo1*.tar.gz`
date should be maintained only foo should be changed foo1
is it possible ? if yes how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554092/unix-move-command-regex

Comment: this is bit different i don't want to change full basename, i just want to change part of the basename, And second part of the basename is date which is not constant(i.e. its not fixed string like "java"). Thank you for reply.

Comment: yes I see, but basically you need a move with regex... anyways a correct question and you got your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BASH string manipulation:

```
f='foo-12APR2014.tar.gz'
nf="foo1-${f#*-}"
```

**Test:**

```
echo "$nf"
foo1-12APR2014.tar.gz
```

PS: If not using BASH then you can use sed:

```
nf=`echo "$f"|sed 's/^foo/foo1/'`
```

Comment: both of them works on bash and busybox shell thank you very much anubhava for lightning fast response.